# Airflow returns "Backfill done" without running tasks

Tags: airflow

I'm running Airflow and attempting to iterate on some task we're building from the command line.

When running a airflow webserver, everything works as expected. But when I run `airflow backfill dag task '2017-08-12'`, airflow returns:

```
[2017-08-15 02:52:55,639] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2017-08-15 02:52:56,144] {models.py:168} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags
2017-08-15 02:52:59,055 - airflow.jobs.BackfillJob - INFO - Backfill done. Exiting
```

...and doesn't actually run the dag.

When using `airflow test` or `airflow run` (i.e. commands involving running a task rather than a dag), it works as expected

Am I making a basic mistake? What can I do to debug from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a task has a `@monthly` schedule, then if you try and run it with a `start_date` mid-month, it will merely state `Backfill done. Exiting.`. If a task has a schedule of `'30 5 * * *'`, this also prevents `backfill` from the command line

(Updated to reflect better information, and [this discussion](https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow?at=5993af6dbc464729748963ae))

Comment: I just found out that the backfill range command does not work if the dag has `schedule_interval=None`. It only runs for the fist day of the range.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run those DAG on that date range already? You will need to `clear` the DAG first then `backfill`. Base on what Maxime mentioned here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/gMY-sc0QVh0

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:

- Execution date specified via `-e` option is outside of the DAG's `[start_date, end_date)` range.
- Even if execution date is between the dates, please keep in mind that if you DAG has `schedule_interval=None` then it won't `backfill` iteratively: it will only run for a single date (specified as `--start_date` or `--end_date` if the first is omitted).